# Core Data Merge policy

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I've implemented core data in my application successfully. Everything was working fine but I got an issue. I'm using merge policy to update records. 
I've two Entities name **Issues** and **Members** with relation one to many. One issue has many members.

Data comes from the server and saved in these two Entities:

```
Object A
Object B
Object C
```

This data comes first time and save in coredata. Data updates on server and when fetching second time , this data comes:

```
Object A
Object B
```

It should update and remove the Object C, but **Object C** still in coredata.
Please help me what i'm doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```
private class func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
}

class func saveIssues(with json: JSON)
{
    let context = getContext()
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Issues", in: context)
    let issue = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context) as! Issues

    issue.setValue(json["Id"].stringValue, forKey: "id")
    issue.setValue(json["Name"].stringValue, forKey: "name")
    issue.setValue(json["CreatedByName"].stringValue, forKey:"createdByName")

    for issueMembers in json["Members"].arrayValue
    {
       let members = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Members", into: context) as! Members
        members.setValue(issueMembers["FullName"].stringValue, forKey: "fullName")
        members.setValue(issueMembers["PictureUrl"].stringValue, forKey: "picture_Url")
        members.setValue(issueMembers["LoginId"]. stringValue, forKey: "loginId")
        issue.addToIssueMembers(members)
        }


  context.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
   do{
        try context.save()
    }catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    } 

}
```

Comment: Add some code showing how you handle updates. Also describe the set of managed object contexts you use (do you set parent context anywhere? when do you save contexts?)

Comment: @AntonFilimonov I've edit my question. Please have a look into my code. Please help me what i'm doing wrong here. Thank you

Comment: I don't see any code to delete no more needed objects. Do you use any uniqeness constraints?

Comment: @AntonFilimonov I'm using unique constraint. "Id" in issues and "loginId" in members are unique constraint.

Comment: @AntonFilimonov I think purpose of using merge policy is no more check for updating , deleting. it handle these operations.

Answer (score 2):

I investigated it a little bit and found that no one merge policy suites your needs: in case of uniqueness constraints, both `NSRollbackMergePolicy` and `NSOverwriteMergePolicy` save only old (existed on persistent store) set of objects in relationship, and both `NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy` and `NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy` save all objects in relationship the object had in two versions (on disk and in memory). So seems like you have to manage the relationship yourself...

Comment: Flow off my app is that it's to fetch everytime latest data from the server and refresh local DB. So in my case merge policy is not useful? Because data may vary every time. So what will be the best approach to cover this scenario?

Comment: @AdnanMajeed It depends on your needs. If it's OK for you, that you always get new object, I'd just remove the old one before creating the new one. If for example you use NSFetchedResultsController and want it to tell you that existing object changed rather then replaced with the new one, then you'll have to 1. request existing object; 2. If it does not exist create the new one. 3. fill object data. 4. Do the same for dependencies (maybe in case of dependencies it'd be ok for you to just delete old and create new)